# The android studio 1.3 stops when loading the components for the project

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the android studio 1.3 and to avoid the extra volume, I did not install the device emulator when installation. I can launch the android studio wizard well, but In the end I have the following problem. Also My system ram is `3` GIG.

```
System Requirements
Windows

    Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003 (32 or 64-bit)
    2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended
    400 MB hard disk space
    At least 1 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
    1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
    Java Development Kit (JDK) 7
    Optional for accelerated emulator: Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
```

Also when I see the task manager in windows it is as follows:

[image]

And the my problem is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Someone else some hours before asked a similar question and someone said that 4 GB isn't much of a power at this time, and I will agree with them. You need some more Ram in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Well `Android Studio` does eat memory sometimes but I'm not sure that ram really is the problem.  Download 1.4 from the `canary channel` and let `Android Studio` install everything it wants.  There's probably a hidden dependency somewhere. 
[Android Canary Channel](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary)